# error: linking with `ld` failed: exit status: 1

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo, solana

I'm trying to follow this guide as my entry into Solana blockchain development. I'm running into an error when I run the command $anchor build

For context, I'm running wsl. I'm not concerned about the warning, but any help would be much appreciated!

Here are the contents of the error:

```
error: linking with `ld` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "ld" "--version-script=/tmp/rustc7rlvlq/list" "--Bdynamic" "--entry=entrypoint" "--threads=1" "-z" "notext" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.solana_twitter.667be1f5-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.23ok8bvhjt9fifog.rcgu.o" "--as-needed" "-L" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps" "-L" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/release/deps" "-L" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib" "-Bstatic" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libanchor_lang-369f9fcce7f9778b.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libbase64-ee92f11b5395c52e.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsolana_program-9fe9cc99ff752644.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libserde_bytes-5207c42260a7c267.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libhex-6cd04f1b9c696e32.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsolana_frozen_abi-f9c2f8b8a627f8aa.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libbs58-fe01222278a2eda8.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libbv-c7c0e796134886cb.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/liblazy_static-809b40aac429888e.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libitertools-c458dae8c4611cd8.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libeither-6eeb62e68a9b8e57.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsha3-24b5c86da1eb0453.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libkeccak-ac25e9c6d97c1dff.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libthiserror-90c773aba6f68987.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsha2-48f21f103c901542.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libopaque_debug-7a932b68d3299c7b.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libdigest-6389a1260a04b96b.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libblock_buffer-a630a7b4c9084931.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libblock_padding-1a56ee8f16ee908c.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libgeneric_array-d7158a87da87264b.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libtypenum-ef879e2476d2db6d.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/liblog-cc2d231fbaac5454.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libcfg_if-1643e4a2c6efb510.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libnum_traits-67afc00ec41f572f.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libbincode-daf7bb0fce4a700c.rlib" 
"/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libserde-e445d83f85708c13.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libborsh-701da45de74b9763.rlib" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libbytemuck-eaed85aa73d5dfbc.rlib" "--start-group" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-b9e47931bb048ddd.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libpanic_abort-cee38af281743742.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd_detect-4bf956fa4dfc36ef.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libhashbrown-419e08fa951207df.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-f389bcb5a4dc00c1.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libunwind-9d2b664eda1e59bf.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libcfg_if-0df5cdc1ad3f0480.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/liblibc-1d523315f98b1675.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/liballoc-38dcdcf486775e23.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-8201043866f2d4dd.rlib" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libcore-a4fd67b7f3cf9226.rlib" "--end-group" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib/libcompiler_builtins-fcfbbdc9d2a94cb9.rlib" "-Bdynamic" "--script" "/tmp/rustc7rlvlq/rustc-bpfel-linkfile.ld" "-znoexecstack" "-L" "/home/tai8910/.cache/solana/v1.20/bpf-tools/rust/lib/rustlib/bpfel-unknown-unknown/lib" "-o" "/home/tai8910/Code/solana-twitter/target/bpfel-unknown-unknown/release/deps/solana_twitter.so" "--gc-sections" "-shared" "-O1"
  = note: ld: unrecognized option '--threads=1'
          ld: use the --help option for usage information


warning: `solana-twitter` (lib) generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `solana-twitter` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the build is not using the correct linker that's part of the BPF tool suite, probably using the default `ld` instead.

Can you make sure that `~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin` is part of your `PATH`?  After that, try simply running `cargo build-bpf` to make sure that the program can build without Anchor.  If it's still failing, you may need to reinstall the Solana tools.